# React: child component is receiving partial props from the parent

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a parent component, plotMap, which gets an array called "plots" from state. Each plot has an id ("_id") property, and a GeoJSON object. I am using this as a key, and mapping "plots", to return a child marker component for each plot. When I iterate through the "plots" array to see the properties of each plot, I can see that each one has an id. However, when I console log the properties of the child components, the id (the key) is nowhere to be found. The GeoJSON, however, shows up just fine. This is also strange because I make the plot having an id property a condition of rendering the child component, and I can see in the log that the plots are being rendered.

Here's what I'm talking about.

Parent component (redacted for brevity):

```
export class PlotMap extends Component {
    markers = props => {
        if (props.plots) {
            return (
                <div>
                    {(props.filteredPlots || props.plots).map(
                        plot =>
                            plot.feature &&
                            plot._id && (
                                <PlotMarker
                                    key={plot._id}
                                    id={plot._id}
                                    geoJSON={plot.feature}
                                    position={centroid(plot.feature).geometry.coordinates}
                                />
                            )
                    )}
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    render() {
        this.props.plots &&
            (this.props.filteredPlots || this.props.plots).forEach(plot => {
                plot.feature && console.log(JSON.stringify(plot._id));
            });

        return (
            <div
                className="col-sm-8 m-auto p-0 flex-column float-right"
                style={{ height: `85vh` }}>
                <Map
                    center={initialMapCenter(this.props)}
                    zoom={initialZoomLevel}
                    zoomControl={true}
                    onZoomend={e => {
                        this.props.setZoomLevel(e.target.getZoom());
                    }}
                    onMoveEnd={e => {
                        this.props.setMapCenter(e.target.getCenter());
                    }}>
                    <LayersControl position="topright">
                        <BaseLayer name="Google Maps Roads">
                            <GoogleLayer googlekey={key} maptype={road} />
                        </BaseLayer>
                        <BaseLayer name="Google Maps Terrain">
                            <GoogleLayer googlekey={key} maptype={terrain} />
                        </BaseLayer>
                        <BaseLayer name="Google Maps Satellite">
                            <GoogleLayer googlekey={key} maptype={satellite} />
                        </BaseLayer>
                        <BaseLayer checked name="Google Maps Hybrid">
                            <GoogleLayer
                                googlekey={key}
                                maptype={hybrid}
                                libraries={['geometry', 'places']}
                            />
                        </BaseLayer>
                    </LayersControl>
                    <SearchBox postion="bottomright" />
                    {this.markers(this.props)}
                </Map>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { Marker, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';

export class PlotMarker extends Component {
    render() {
        const { key, id, position, geoJSON, zoomLevel } = this.props;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.key));
        if (zoomLevel > 14) {
            return <GeoJSON id={id} data={geoJSON} />;
        }
        return <Marker id={id} position={position} />;
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        selectedPlot: state.plots.selectedPlot,
        plotBeingEdited: state.plots.plotBeingEdited,
        zoomLevel: state.plots.zoomLevel
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(PlotMarker);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keys aren't passed as a property to the child on React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

> Keys serve as a hint to React but they don’t get passed to your components. **If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name**:

Comment: I've deleted the key prop inside the child element, and am also passing the id as "id", but the child is not seeing it.

Comment: Never mind, got it, thanks.

Comment: If this was the correct answer don't forget to mark it so :)